# Who uses Freesound.org on a regular basis?

Tags: recording, location-recording, collaboration, libraries

Imagine, if 20 years ago somebody told you there would be a method for people to share and contribute sounds from all over the world instantly; well, that's what we have with [freesound.org](http://www.freesound.org/). Whenever I hit a wall with my personal libraries I can do a quick search there and usually find something unique, and many times the recordings are available at professional sample and bit rates.

Who else out there uses this great resource?

Answer (score 6):

I've used it once or twice before. The problem I have with it is the crediting clause in the creative commons license (see below), unless I'm misunderstanding it. Let's say I use 10 sounds for a film, that's a big chunk of credit space :-(. Getting a producer or product manager to agree to significantly multiply the credit space they give to the sound department for a few particular sound effects ain't easy.

Attribution and Notice.

1.

```
  If You distribute, publicly display, publicly perform, or publicly digitally perform the Work or any Derivative Works or Collective Works, You must keep intact all copyright notices for the Work and give the Original Author credit reasonable to the medium or means You are utilizing by conveying the name (or pseudonym if applicable) of the Original Author if supplied; the title of the Work if supplied; to the extent reasonably practicable, provide the Uniform Resource Identifier, if any, that Licensor specifies to be associated with the Work or a Derivative Work, unless such Uniform Resource Identifier does not refer to the copyright notice or licensing information for the Work; and in the case of a Derivative Work, provide a credit identifying the use of the Work in the Derivative Work (e.g., "Remix of the Work by Original Author," or "Inclusion of a portion of the Work by Original Author in collage"). Such credit may be implemented in any reasonable manner; provided, however, that in the case of a Derivative Work or Collective Work, at a minimum such credit will appear where any other comparable authorship credit appears and in a manner at least as prominent as such other comparable authorship credit.
```

Comment: that's a lot of legalese…I don't think my brain can comprehend it right now.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't used freesound specifically because I have zero control over credits and don't want to get burned down the line. But it is useful for inspiration.

Comment: I love the concept but it's pretty useless as there's no way I can get any credits added to any of the shows I work on. Shame on the one hand but nice people aren't being ripped off on the other.

Comment: same, I cant even consider using anything from freesound with that credit clause... 

Answer (score 1):

Freesound is great! It s always very handy when you need specific sounds that you don t have, or you don t have the time to record.
It s great!

Comment: do you credit the sounds you use from there?

Comment: I just use it a couple of times when i needed a very specific sound while i was editing and the director wanted to check out the scene.They were replaced because the quality generally isnt great. 

Answer (score 1):

Freesound is fantastic, and always good for those hard to find recordings....

Comment: do you credit the sounds you use from there?

Comment: Usually give the editor and producer a credit list. Luckily, it never comes to more than 2 or 3 files per project. 

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I've ignored it until last week because some sounds that my friends used in their videos were quite simply horrendous (quality-wise)... but I surrendered and I'm realising it's not all that bad :)

Answer (score 1):

Lots of free (and terrible) recordings.

There really needs to be some kind of quality control, rating system, etc. that actually works.

Answer (score 1):

I used Freesound for some of the sounds used in my sound replacement project for F.E.A.R 3.  At the end of the trailer I credited all the sounds.  I wonder if it would be acceptable to refer viewer to credits posted on a website as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've noticed by now, but I use it quite a bit.  I absolutely love it -- it's a perfect resource for guys like me without money. :D

Comment: And, to preemptively attack your question, Tim... Yes, I credit everything.  I haven't made a dime off a sound design project, so I don't have to worry about the commercial side of things.

Comment: @Dave, I find freesound to be a great resource, as well. I'm curious - what types of projects are you using the sounds for, and how do you give credit for them?

Comment: @Jay  I've used it on games and short films.  I credit it the exact same way every time, and that's exactly as their attribution list prints out.  That's mainly because I'm lazy, though.

http://www.vimeo.com/14286038  <-- That's how I attribute it.  For projects with more attribution, like my demo reel will have, I'll throw a put a list on my website and put the link at the end of the video "For the complete Freesound.org attribution list, go to www.davematney.com/democredits"

Answer (score 1):

well, I upload once in a while some sounds to it, mainly, because I want to see, if my sound are good or miserable =). Problem with freesound is, that most of the people just download stuff and never upload anything, so pushing each other is difficult sometimes. Last year I used some stuff for a no-budget short movie, but you need some time to get proper sounds.
Since then, I never downloaded stuff again, not because the sounds are bad, but because I want to expand my own library.

Answer (score 0):

Great feedback, all.

I thought I understood that, so long as you make note on freesound.org itself as to how you used the sound, you were all good. No?

Comment: If that *is* the case, then great. Where on the site do you post it? Here's where it's tricky: "give the Original Author credit reasonable to the medium". What is reasonable for the medium? If it's a film, I think "reasonable" means it goes in the end credits, as there's no precedent for referring to a website. For games, it may be reasonable to refer to a website.

I'm no Lawyer, I'd be curious to hear what the folks at freesound.org have to say about the matter.

Comment: I've only ever seen freesound in the credits of a film once, for a scream that was used in Children of Men
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Children_of_men.jpg


Comment: If only I was related to the Wilhelm screamer... I'd be rich via lawsuits...

Answer (score 0):

what if you combined 8 freesound's into your own thing?